# Installation was unsuccessful

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I create cab file.when i install on to my real device.i am getting this type of error.-
                   installation was unsuccessful.The programme or setting cannot be installed because it doesnot have sufficent permissions.

Could anyone help me????]

thx in advance....

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your application is installed in a **subfolder** under "Program Files", and that only shortcuts are created under the "Programs" folder.

I once had the same error message but can't remember which mistake I made: either forgot the subfolder, or mismatched "Programs" and "Program Files".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are installing to a WinMo phone and the phone [has a security policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc182305.aspx) set by the provider.  You'll have to get the CAB signed (or decrease the device security if it's allowed) to get the CAB to install.

Answer (score 0):

What is your CAB file doing? In which directories are the files going? Are you trying to set certain registry values which might be protected?